# How to find if CALayer is double clicked in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

I developed a 3d cube consist of 6 layer side by side to form a cube type structure. I am getting the single tap using touch event but the double tap is not working.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if ([touches count] == 1) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Single tap");
    }
   if ([touches count] == 2) 
    {
      NSLog(@"Double tap");  // Not Working
    }
}
```

How can i get the double tap working ?

Comment: Clicked? With a mouse? Or did you mean tapped? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Besides being able to recognize a tap gesture in your app, you’ll
>   probably want to distinguish a single tap, a double tap, or even a
>   triple tap. Use a touch’s`tapCount`property to determine the number of
>   times the user tapped a view.

Each touch returned in the NSSet is not exactly a tap. The OS recognize a double tap and returns it as one UITouch, so you can try to handle the event after the touch ended by using:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *aTouch in touches) {
        if (aTouch.tapCount >= 2) {
             // The view responds to the tap
             [self respondToDoubleTapGesture:aTouch];
        }
    }
}
```

If it still doesn't work and you are using `UITapGestureRecognizer` take a look at the property `numberOfTapsRequired`. If it is set to 1, try to change it to 2.

```
yourTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
```

The [Apple Dev documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html) may also help you understand how to use the `UIGestureRecognizer`s correctly.